# How to Handle custom event which has exception on new object

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, exception, event-handling

i am creating a new object that passes a string value as the only constructor.

```
Dim o As New Widget("widgetname")
```

In my Widget constructor, an Exception occurs and I raise an event and event handler.

```
Public Class Widget
    Public Event ConnectionException As EventHandler

    Sub New(ByVal name As String)
        _name= f
        RaiseEvent ConnectionException(Me, New EventArgs())
    End Sub
End Class
```

On my page that calls the Widget, I create the object, declare the listener

```
Dim o = New Widget("widgetname")
AddHandler o.ConnectionException, AddressOf ConnectionError
```

and the handler routine.

```
Sub ConnectionError(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Response.Write("Computer says no.")
End Sub
```

Logically and syntaxically, I think it makes sense but nothing is displayed, and the exception error is displayed.

Am I doing something wrong in the referencing of the event handler?

Comment: I don't see any exception handling

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the constructor is called in your code before you've wired up the connection error event.  In theory, the event wouldn't be fired if there was an error initializing the constructor.

I would consider moving the connection opening into an Open sub.  That way, after you initialize the object you can wire up your events, then call open (much like an IDbConnection works although it just tosses an Exception and doesn't raise any events).

Comment: So how wouldthe best method to be handle Exceptions to fail elegantly rather than the yellow screen of death in web applications?   Would it be best to put it around a Try...Catch..Finally. and add a property IsConnected to test if the connection works?

Answer (score 0):

You are raising the event in the constructor but you don't attach the event handler until after the constructor has completed, so the event has already come and gone by the time you start listening for it.  There's no way around that with an event because you can't handle an event of an object until you have a reference to the object, which you can't have until the constructor has completed.  You'll need to set a property in the constructor instead and then test that after the object has been created.

Comment: So am I right is saying there is no way in the .NET landscape environment to have a handler with a constructor method without referencing it?

Comment: What you just asked makes no actual sense but I will reiterate that you can't handle an event of an object that doesn't exist and an object doesn't exist until it's constructor has completed.